# Positive definitness of $f(|x|^\gamma)$, $0<\gamma<1$

Tags: pr.probability, fourier-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, fourier-transform

Let $f(x)$ be a  positive definite function on $x \in R^d$.  Assume $f(x)$ is radial ,
so $f(x)$ is a function of $|x|$, let's say $g(|x|):=f(x)$. How can I show that
$g(|x|^\gamma)$ is positive definite for $0<\gamma<1$?

Any hints will be greatly appreciated.
I have found the following Theorem:  A continuous function $\varphi:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is positive definite and radial on $\mathbb{R}^s$ for all $s$ if and only if it is of the form
$$
\varphi(r)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-r^2 t^2} d \mu(t),
$$
where $\mu$ is a finite non-negative Borel measure on $[0, \infty)$.
$ e^{-r^{2\gamma} t^2}$ is positive definite but I do not know how that helps me.
UPDATE:  the problem with this theorem, the function has to be positive definite/radial for ALL $s$. At the moment I can only show that my function is positive definite for $s=1$. I suspect it is positive definite for $s=2,3$. Are there other results for specific $s$?

Comment: as a start, a composition $m(b(x))$ of completely monotone function $m(x)$ and Bernstein function $b(x)$ is completely monotone function; $x^\gamma$, $0<\gamma<1$ is Bernstein  function

Comment: Since $ e^{-r^{2\gamma} t^2}$ can be represented as a Gaussian mixture, $\phi(r^{\gamma})$ is radial

Comment: Can you give a reference to the theorem you cited?

Comment: http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/603_ch2.pdf

Comment: @TanyaVladi I see it now,  A function $\varphi$ is completely monotone on $[0, \infty)$ if and only if $\Phi=$ $\varphi\left(\|\cdot\|^2\right)$ is positive definite and radial on $\mathbb{R}^s$ for all $s$, since the composition of completely monotone and Bernstein is completely monotone we are back to positive definite.

Comment: @AlexeyS : How do show this for $s=1$?

Comment: @David Roberts I posted the solution BEFORE Iosif posted his